# Jetpack compose - how do I refresh a screen when app returns to foreground

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack-compose

I need to automatically refresh an Android Compose screen when the app returns to the foreground.

I have an that requires permissions and location services.

If the user has switched any of these off a list is drawn of the items that need to be changed. When the user goes to Settings and the app returns to the foreground I would like the list to refresh to reflect the changes.

I am using Compose and Compose navigation. I have looked and I can't figure out the equivalent of onResume lifecycle event that could be used to trigger the refresh.

Any ideas would be gratefully received as I am at a loss.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Using oficial API** (requires Lifecycle Runtime Compose 2.7.0):

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.0")
```

The official way to detect `Lifecycle.State` changes would be using the following code snippet:

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val lifecycleState by lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentStateFlow.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(lifecycleState) {
    // Do something with your state
    // You may want to use DisposableEffect or other alternatives
    // instead of LaunchedEffect
    when (lifecycleState) {
        Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED -> {}
        Lifecycle.State.INITIALIZED -> {}
        Lifecycle.State.CREATED -> {}
        Lifecycle.State.STARTED -> {}
        Lifecycle.State.RESUMED -> {}
    }
}
```

`collectStateAsState` is a convenience extension function that collects State changes by using Lifecycle's new property `currentStateFlow`. So the code above would be the same as doing:

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val state by lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentStateFlow.collectAsState()

LaunchedEffect(state) {
    // Do something with your state
    // You may want to use DisposableEffect or other alternatives 
    // instead of LaunchedEffect
}
```

Remember to import `androidx.compose.runtime.getValue` to [access directly](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) the `Lifecycle.State`.

As mentioned by @HåkonSchia, you can also use variations of DiposableEffect that also take in consideration the Lifecycle:

```
LifecycleStartEffect(Unit) {
    // Do something on start or launch effect

    onStopOrDispose {
        // Do something on stop or dispose effect
    }
}

LifecycleResumeEffect(Unit) {
    // Do something on resume or launch effect

    onPauseOrDispose {
        // Do something on pause or dispose effect
    }
}
```

**Old answer:**

Compose is not aware of state changes like `onPause` or `onResume`, you have to handle it using the parent activity's methods.

An example would be a `LiveData` instance in your activity that updates each time `onResume` is executed and observe it as a state in your main parent composable.

Let's take a look at the following example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Use whatever type your prefer/require, this is just an example
    private val exampleLiveData = MutableLiveData("")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            // Your main composable
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // Save the state into a variable otherwise it won't work
                val state = exampleLiveData.observeAsState()
                Log.d("EXAMPLE", "Recomposing screen - ${state.value}")

                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // Save whatever you want in your live data, this is just an example
        exampleLiveData.value = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

As you can see in this example, I have a `LiveData` property in my activity that containts a String. Whenever `onResume` is executed the property is updated with the new timestamp and the observing composable is recomposed.

Comment: Thanks @Abdelilah. That's what I thought but I really hoped there would be something built in to Compose to help with this situation. We have built our app with Compose navigation too so there is only one Activity and one Fragment in the entire app. This is the first real issue that we have encountered but your solution is similar to what we were thinking but using the timestamp is nicer. Thank you.

Comment: Please include all the dependencies that we need to include in order to make this thing work. I'm unable to find 2.7.0 version. Add the content of your build.gradle file. Thank you!

Comment: @nutella_eater as mentioned in the warning, the release is not out yet. The Android team usually releases a new version of the lifecycle libraries every 2 weeks but this time seems to be a bit later, since it's been almost 4 weeks, probably because it includes quite some changes. The proposed solution is based on this commit in case you are interested https://github.com/androidx/androidx/commit/b75b447af3d27aed4b4bc5a826e6e92cd0aaff34

Comment: Seems like 2.7.0 also includes convenience functions like `LifecycleStartEffect()` and `LifecycleResumeEffect()` https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime-compose/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/compose/LifecycleEffect.kt

Comment: Thanks @HåkonSchia, I've added it as well as updating the dependencies and the code snippet.

Comment: Destroy is never called. And when you press the back button to go back to the previous page, it's calling Lifecycle.State.STARTED

Comment: BE AWARE that `LifecycleStartEffect.onStopOrDispose` is called twice on navigating to another screen! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77888217/lifecyclestarteffect-onstopordispose-is-called-twice-on-navigating-to-another-sc

Answer (score 91):

I came up with this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun OnLifecycleEvent(onEvent: (owner: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit) {
    val eventHandler = rememberUpdatedState(onEvent)
    val lifecycleOwner = rememberUpdatedState(LocalLifecycleOwner.current)
    
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner.value) {
        val lifecycle = lifecycleOwner.value.lifecycle
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { owner, event ->
            eventHandler.value(owner, event)
        }

        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work just fine. But there may be some issues in some cases so be careful.
It is also possible that there is some redundant code.

Usage:

```kotlin
OnLifecycleEvent { owner, event ->
    // do stuff on event
    when (event) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> { /* stuff */ }
        else                      -> { /* other stuff */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: An example on how to use this would be helpful

Comment: Why `lifecycleOwner` has to change? Is not it sth read-only?

Comment: In production, we did observed some looping issues in onResume(). i.e it keep calling the Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> { /* stuff */ } block in loops

Answer (score 52):

I slightly improved **@JojoIV** answer and made it flat usage without callback like you observe `LiveData` in compose what **@Abdelilah El Aissaoui** answered

```
@Composable
fun Lifecycle.observeAsState(): State<Lifecycle.Event> {
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY) }
    DisposableEffect(this) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            state.value = event
        }
        this@observeAsState.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            this@observeAsState.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    return state
}
```

and then usage

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable() {
   val lifecycleState = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle.observeAsState()
   val state = lifecycleState.value
   // or val lifecycleState by LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle.observeAsState()
  // will re-render someComposable each time lifecycleState will change
}
```

Comment: This answer was useful when using resume and pause only, but not start and stop.

Comment: @bambam why is that?

Comment: Print (the `state` before return) and (the `event` of `LifecycleEventObserver`) in the first snippet . In my case the former only called RESUME and PAUSE.
I'm not sure, but it seems that there is an omission by passing through the compose state rather than passing the event right away. If it doesn't reproduce, I'll do some more testing. @JoshuaKing

Answer (score 27):

example from google site

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
  lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current,
  onStart: () -> Unit, // Send the 'started' analytics event
  onStop: () -> Unit   // Send the 'stopped' analytics event
) {
    // Safely update the current lambdas when a new one is provided
    val currentOnStart by rememberUpdatedState(onStart)
    val currentOnStop by rememberUpdatedState(onStop)

    // If `lifecycleOwner` changes, dispose and reset the effect
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        // Create an observer that triggers our remembered callbacks
        // for sending analytics events
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {
                currentOnStart()
            } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) {
                currentOnStop()
            }
        }

        // Add the observer to the lifecycle
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }

    /* Home screen content */
}
```

Full description of how it works in google site
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect

Answer (score 10):

### Here is solution in 2023

Create utility function:

```
@Composable
fun rememberLifecycleEvent(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current): Lifecycle.Event {
    var state by remember { mutableStateOf(Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY) }
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            state = event
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    return state
}
```

Use it in your screen composable:

```
val lifecycleEvent = rememberLifecycleEvent()
LaunchedEffect(lifecycleEvent) {
     if (lifecycleEvent == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
        // initiate data reloading
     }
}
```

Source: [Jetpack Compose with Lifecycle-Aware Composables](https://scribe.rip/jetpack-compose-with-lifecycle-aware-composables-7bd5d6793e0)

Answer (score 5):

#### Simple Solution in 2024

Since version `2.7.0` of the [androidx lifecycle library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle)

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.0")
```

We can simply do the following to execute a function whenever the current `LifecycleOwner` of a composable goes into `ON_RESUME` lifecycle state. Of course you can use any other lifecycle event of your choice instead:

```
// Call this like any other SideEffect in your composable
LifecycleEventEffect(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
    // refresh your data
}
```

If you want to handle something in `onResume` as well as `onPause`, you can make use of an alternative side effect, called `LifecycleResumeEffect`:

```
LifecycleResumeEffect(Unit) {
    // viewModel.runOnResume()
    onPauseOrDispose {
        // viewModel.runOnPause()
    }
}
```

Just to mention, there is a third option called `LifecycleStartEffect` that has the functionality but for `ON_START` and `ON_STOP` & `ON_DESTROY`

Answer (score 4):

i changed **@ojoIV** code to this
(if your composable code is in Activity)

```
@Composable
fun ComponentActivity.LifecycleEventListener(event: (Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit) {
    val eventHandler by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = event)
    val lifecycle = this@LifecycleEventListener.lifecycle
    DisposableEffect(lifecycle) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            eventHandler(event)
        }
        
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
LifecycleEventListener(event = { lifecycleEvent ->
    when (lifecycleEvent ) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE -> {}
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> {}
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {}
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {}
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> {}
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY -> {}
        else -> return@LifecycleEventListener
    }
})
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks ! but link in below is dead .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following helper method:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LifecycleEffect(event: Lifecycle.Event, skip: Int = 1, handler: () -> Unit) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    var skipped by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, e ->
            if (e == event) {
                if (skipped < skip) {
                    skipped += 1
                } else {
                    handler()
                }
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

the observer receives the first event by default, this allows skipping it, it's also pretty convenient to use:

```kotlin
LifecycleEffect(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {
    //...
}
```