# Jetpack compose how to recompose when coming to foreground

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to make status bar hidden and I've managed to do it like so using the accompanist library:

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false
```

The issue is that when the app goes to background and comes to foreground, this piece of code is not run and therefore the status bar is shown again. How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Did my answer solve your question? If so, please accept it. Otherwise, let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `OnLifecycleEvent` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807899/3585796).

```kotlin
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
OnLifecycleEvent { _, event ->
    when (event) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME,
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_START,
        -> {
            systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false
        }
        else -> Unit
    }
}
```

`OnLifecycleEvent`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun OnLifecycleEvent(onEvent: (owner: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit) {
    val eventHandler = rememberUpdatedState(onEvent)
    val lifecycleOwner = rememberUpdatedState(LocalLifecycleOwner.current)

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner.value) {
        val lifecycle = lifecycleOwner.value.lifecycle
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { owner, event ->
            eventHandler.value(owner, event)
        }

        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```