# Jetpack Compose - How to Identify user is coming via back navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I come across requirement where I have to do certain task when user is coming via back navigation flow.

Suppose : Currently user is on A Screen and on button click it got navigated to B Screen.
On B Screen I'm using `BackHandler` to navigate user to back screen using `navController.navigateUp()` as this code working perfectly to navigate user to back screen.

But I'm unable to identify is user coming via back navigation or initial launch flow.

**Already Tried Solution :** `val isFromBackNavigation = parentNavController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination?.route == AppNav.Wishlist.route`
This returns true for initial launch also.

Comment: you need to know about lifecycle of jetpack views . you can check this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546962/jetpack-compose-how-do-i-refresh-a-screen-when-app-returns-to-foreground